# NodeJS app with lots of timeouts

Tags: node.js, settimeout

I'm creating app which involves running some delayed tasks, something as follow:

```
app.get('/doit', function(req, res) {
  var timeout = 1000*60*60*8; // timeout between 1 hour and several days 
  var task=setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('doing delayed task...');
  },timeout);  
  res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

The question is: will it impact performance if there are lots of such tasks? (a few thousands and more)

Is there better way to do it?

Comment: I have a feeling you should be using cron instead - take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: You might be worried about multiple, unintentional requests. Modern browsers may access ```/doit``` while typing or if it is a bookmark e.g. for preloading or similar features. This would result in scheduling your delayed task multiple times.

Comment: I will use post requests with additional data, so it shouldn't be a problem. app.get(); just for example. Anyway, thanks - I'll take it into account for the future :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nodejs is event based so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Its unlikely to cause any major performance issues unless if the number of such tasks is really really high, but then there would be performance issues anyway.A better solution to your problem depends on what you are trying to achieve. It would help if you could provide some details.

In case you want run a task periodically, it would be better to use [cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) 
.In case you are just waiting for some event to happen, then I would suggest you to use  [node events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html). Anyways, there are still a lot of things where setTimeout still is the best available solution , in that case, go ahead and use it.

Comment: The app is kind of a game. For example, user initiated constructing of a house and this construction takes 8 hours. So it is not periodic, just delayed reaction on user's action.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use nodejs for game development. Nodejs is not ideal for computationally intensive tasks. Although I have no experience in Game Development, but I think such tasks are usually done with C/C++. You may consider using nodejs for communication between players but not for actual processing in game.
As far as your scenario is concerned, I am pretty much sure there are better solutions available. Using setTimeout sure would work fine for smaller, less used application but will not scale well.

Comment: I thought about C++, but due to my poor experience it'll take a lot of time ( Besides, I'd say this idea is just so-called game - it doesn't involve any dynamic calculations, just simple math. Maybe, if it have great success, I'll move it to the C++ core )

Comment: Thnx, it's going to be fun )